# Заблокирован каталог /usr/bin

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chmod

Из-за опечатки в команде chmod оказался заблокирован каталог /usr/bin в Ubuntu 16.04.

Результат команды `ls -l`:

> d---------   2 root root 69632 окт  8 15:51 bin

При попытке использования `chmod` ошибка:

> bash: /usr/lib/command-not-found: /usr/bin/python3: плохой
>   интерпретатор: Отказано в доступе

Есть ли возможность восстановить права?

Comment: Есть ли возможность загрузиться в single-user-mode и есть ли пароль от рута?

Comment: Решено загрузкой с live cd и восстановлением прав для папки через sudo

Answer (score -1):

chmod находится в /bin. `/bin/chmod 755 /usr/bin` достаточно, чтобы исправить проблему.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: утверждение основано на том очевидном факте, что программа измения прав доступа доступна, так как находится в каталоге /bin. человеку же нужно исправить проблему в /usr/bin.